# PL SQL identifier must be declared

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hey I am new to PL SQL and what I am trying to do is to get the user input and use it in the procedure.Hereby I have attached my code and the error message that I get. I realized that I get this error only for strings. Such as JAN FEB and IT_PROG,

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_job_history AS
  2
  3   p_employee_id NUMBER (6);
  4   p_start_date DATE ;
  5   p_end_date DATE ;
  6   p_job_id VARCHAR2(10) ;
  7   p_department_id NUMBER ;
  8
  9  BEGIN
 10
 11    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Attempt to insert new record into Job History Database');
 12    --  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Number ' || &employee_id);
 13
 14
 15
 16    p_employee_id := &p_employee_id;
 17    p_start_date := &p_start_date;
 18    p_end_date := &p_end_date;
 19    p_job_id := &p_job_id;
 20    p_department_id := &p_department_id;
 21
 22
 23  INSERT INTO job_history(employee_id,start_date,end_date,job_id,department_id)
 24  VALUES (p_employee_id,p_start_date,p_end_date,p_job_id,p_department_id); -- try to insert new record
 25    COMMIT;
 26  END;
 27  /
Enter value for employee_id: 103
old  12:   --  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Number ' || &employee_id);
new  12:   --  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Number ' || 103);
old  16:   p_employee_id := &p_employee_id;
new  16:   p_employee_id := 103;
old  17:   p_start_date := &p_start_date;
new  17:   p_start_date := 03-JAN-06;
old  18:   p_end_date := &p_end_date;
new  18:   p_end_date := 02-FEB-20;
old  19:   p_job_id := &p_job_id;
new  19:   p_job_id := IT_PROG;
old  20:   p_department_id := &p_department_id;
new  20:   p_department_id := 60;

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for PROCEDURE ADD_JOB_HISTORY:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
17/3     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
17/22    PLS-00201: identifier 'JAN' must be declared
18/3     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
18/20    PLS-00201: identifier 'FEB' must be declared
19/3     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
19/15    PLS-00201: identifier 'IT_PROG' must be declared
```

Comment: use quoted substitution variables for their counterparts are of type date and varchar2  such as `'&p_start_date'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `p_start_date := &p_start_date;` you need to use `p_start_date := TO_DATE('&p_start_date','DD-MON-YY');` because p_Start_Date is defined as a DATE and you are (sort of) attempting to assign a string to it.

Your clue would be where line 17 was resolved `new  17:   p_start_date := 03-JAN-06;` where you see the string presented without quotes in the assignment to the DATE variable.

You need TO_DATE in there so that you can account for the date format you have chosen.